# VC6: List compiler errors

Tags: visual-c++-6

I need to update an old dll file that was written in VC6 by a former collegue. 
I have never worked with VC6.

I don't want to update the project to VC2010 because I am afraid that I might get into real trouble in regards of dependencies.

I tried to compile the old project in VC6 now, but the compiler states that there 20 errors.

So far so good, but I just don't see where the errors are, and the info that there are 20 errors do not get me any further.

Is there a way to have VC6 tell me where exactely the compilation errors are?

Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, if you are dealing with VC6 on a daily basis as I do too, I have found these tools useful. http://www.wholetomato.com/ and https://daffodil.codeplex.com/. If you use daffodil, I think in theory it could help make an upgrade to pure 2010+ much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. 
I played around with Clean, Compile All, then Clean again and Compile All again, and finally (after a few rounds) the compiler did not only state that there WERE errors but also which errors/where they are.